# Passwordless ssh login using nameserver.local in my home network

Tags: ssh

In my home network I have two Linux Mint pcs. The one I want to connect to is named "abacaxi" with ip address 177.168.0.121. I was able to deploy ssh keys and I am also able to do ssh pass-wordless login to abacaxi but using abacaxi's ip address:

```
ssh myUname@177.168.0.121
Last login: Thu Jun 29 14:35:11 2023 from 177.168.0.23
```

However, if I do:

```
ssh myUname@abacaxi.local
```

I get:

```
myUname@abacaxi.local's password: 
Last login: Thu Jun 29 14:29:08 2023 from 177.168.0.23
```

i.e. I had to use my password to login. Is it possible to remedy this so I don't have to enter any password and just use the ssh keys?

Thanks in advance